# Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Simple and appropriate data organization can challenge Solidity newcomers. It  wants us to organize everything in ways many of us aren’t accustomed to.

Are there well-solved general patterns for routine on-chain data organization?

Comment: which kind of storage?  I note there's not yet a sorted storage in the examples.

Comment: Solidity CRUD Library (2019) implements Mapped Structs with Delete: https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-epilogue-e563e794fde

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Here are *some* simple and useful patterns in increasing order of utility.

Event logs are omitted for brevity. In practice, it's desirable to emit events for every important state change.

**Simple List Using Array**

Strengths

- Reliably chronological order
- Provides a count
- Random access by Row Number (not Id)

Weaknesses

- No random access by Id
- No assurance of uniqueness
- No check for duplicates
- Uncontrolled growth of the list

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract simpleList {

  struct EntityStruct {
    address entityAddress;
    uint entityData;
    // more fields
  }

  EntityStruct[] public entityStructs;

  function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(uint rowNumber) {
    EntityStruct memory newEntity;
    newEntity.entityAddress = entityAddress;
    newEntity.entityData    = entityData;
    return entityStructs.push(newEntity)-1;
  }

  function getEntityCount() public constant returns(uint entityCount) {
    return entityStructs.length;
  }
}
```

**Mapping with Struct**

Strengths

- Random access by unique Id
- Assurance of Id Uniqueness
- Enclose arrays, mappings, structs within each "record"

Weaknesses

- Unable to enumerate the keys
- Unable to count the keys
- Needs a manual check to distinguish a default from an explicitly "all 0"
  record

Example:

```
contract mappingWithStruct {

  struct EntityStruct {
    uint entityData;
    bool isEntity;
  }

  mapping (address => EntityStruct) public entityStructs;

  function isEntity(address entityAddress) public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {
    return entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity;
  }

  function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
    if(isEntity(entityAddress)) revert(); 
    entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
    entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity = true;
    return true;
  }

  function deleteEntity(address entityAddress) public returns(bool success) {
    if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity = false;
    return true;
  }

  function updateEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
    if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Array of Structs with Unique Ids**

Strengths

- Random access by Row number
- Assurance of Id uniqueness
- Enclose arrays, mappings and structs with each "record"

Weaknesses

- No random access by Id
- Uncontrolled growth of the list

Example:

```
contract arrayWithUniqueIds {

  struct EntityStruct {
    address entityAddress;
    uint entityData;
  }

  EntityStruct[] public entityStructs;
  mapping(address => bool) knownEntity;

  function isEntity(address entityAddress) public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {
    return knownEntity[entityAddress];
  }

  function getEntityCount() public constant returns(uint entityCount) {
    return entityStructs.length;
  }

  function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(uint rowNumber) {
    if(isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    EntityStruct memory newEntity;
    newEntity.entityAddress = entityAddress;
    newEntity.entityData = entityData;
    knownEntity[entityAddress] = true;
    return entityStructs.push(newEntity) - 1;
  }

  function updateEntity(uint rowNumber, address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
    if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    if(entityStructs[rowNumber].entityAddress != entityAddress) revert();
    entityStructs[rowNumber].entityData    = entityData;
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Mapped Structs with Index**

Strengths

- Random access by unique Id or row number
- Assurance of Id uniqueness
- Enclose arrays, mappings and structs within each "record"
- List maintains order of declaration
- Count the records
- Enumerate the Ids
- "Soft" delete an item by setting a boolean

Weaknesses

- Uncontrolled growth of the list

Example:

```
contract MappedStructsWithIndex {

  struct EntityStruct {
    uint entityData;
    bool isEntity;
  }

  mapping(address => EntityStruct) public entityStructs;
  address[] public entityList;

  function isEntity(address entityAddress) public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {
      return entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity;
  }
  
  function getEntityCount() public constant returns(uint entityCount) {
    return entityList.length;
  }

  function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(uint rowNumber) {
    if(isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
    entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity = true;
    return entityList.push(entityAddress) - 1;
  }

  function updateEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
    if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData    = entityData;
    return true;
  }
}
```

**Mapped Structs with Delete-enabled Index**

Strengths

- Random access by unique Id or row number
- Assurance of Id uniqueness
- Enclose arrays, mapping and structs within each "record"
- Count the records
- Enumerate the ids
- Logically control the size of the active list with delete function

Weaknesses

- Marginally increased code complexity
- Marginally higher storage costs
- Key list is inherently unordered

**UPDATE, 2019**

This pattern is available as a library for Solidity 0.5.1: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/solidity-crud-epilogue-e563e794fde, https://github.com/rob-Hitchens/UnorderedKeySet

Example:

```
contract mappedWithUnorderedIndexAndDelete {

  struct EntityStruct {
    uint entityData;
    uint listPointer;
  }

  mapping(address => EntityStruct) public entityStructs;
  address[] public entityList;

  function isEntity(address entityAddress) public constant returns(bool isIndeed) {
    if(entityList.length == 0) return false;
    return (entityList[entityStructs[entityAddress].listPointer] == entityAddress);
  }

  function getEntityCount() public constant returns(uint entityCount) {
    return entityList.length;
  }

  function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
    if(isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
    entityStructs[entityAddress].listPointer = entityList.push(entityAddress) - 1;
    return true;
  }

  function updateEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityData) public returns(bool success) {
    if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityData;
    return true;
  }

  function deleteEntity(address entityAddress) public returns(bool success) {
    if(!isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
    uint rowToDelete = entityStructs[entityAddress].listPointer;
    address keyToMove   = entityList[entityList.length-1];
    entityList[rowToDelete] = keyToMove;
    entityStructs[keyToMove].listPointer = rowToDelete;
    entityList.length--;
    return true;
  }

}
```

This last one has an explainer here: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-2-ed8d8b4f74ec#.ekc22r5lf

and here: https://bitbucket.org/rhitchens2/soliditycrud/src/83703dcaf4d0c4b0d6adc0377455c4f257aa29a7/docs/?at=master

Folder Tree Example: [How can we organize storage of a folder or object tree in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13845/how-can-we-organize-storage-of-a-folder-or-object-tree-in-solidity/13846#13846)

Linked List example shows a way to maintain an ordered list using a library. https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/linkedList.sol
0

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108360/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-hitchens-are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-pa).

Answer (score 25):

Adding to Rob's answer, please use revert() as an alternative of throw.From version 0.4.13 the **throw keyword is deprecated** and will be phased out in the future. Read here for more information: [require, assert and revert in solidity.](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html?highlight=revert)

So, as an example you should change

```
if(isEntity(entityAddress)) throw;
```

to

```
if(isEntity(entityAddress)) revert();
```

in above code provided by Rob.

Comment: Here's the updated code examples using `revert()`: https://ethfiddle.com/PgDM-drAc9

Comment: Thanks, James! I'm sure that will help people. One could also use `require()` but that would mean reversing all the rules ... `if(bad) revert()` => `require(!bad)`

Comment: What is the main difference between `throw` and `revert()`? Do they do the same thing, by reverting back all the states? @Abhishek Sinha && @Rob Hitchens

Comment: Starting `solc 0.4.13`, `revert`, `require` and `assert` deprecate `throw`. They differ slightly from the original `throw` in the details such as gas destruction. Have a look over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15166/difference-between-require-and-assert-and-the-difference-between-revert-and-thro

Answer (score 3):

Great answer by [Rob Hitchens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/5549/rob-hitchens). Would like to point out to a minor breaking change in the code mentioned.
In the `newEntity` function of the `simpleList` contract, the author has used `return entityStructs.push(newEntity)-1;`

Ever since Solidity version 0.6.0, the array.push() function does not return anything. Please refer to the answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/87791/73743.
So, the `return entityStructs.push(newEntity)-1;` part of the code breaks the smart contract.

Comment: That's quite right. Breaking changes happen. Hopefully readers will understand the gist of what's happening and know how to refactor or have a look at the library for more up-to-date examples (2017!). `array--` has been replaced by `.pop`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks [Rob](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/5549/rob-hitchens) for inspiration!

[Here](https://snowtrace.io/address/0x30b45b112df3d204e3a078e2419cf62a47687d55#code) is extended version of **Mapped Structs with Delete-enabled Index** that also support nested mappings, "unstructured" data and ownership

Hope it will help someone

Comment: Link only answer are discouraged. It is better to include the main idea in the answer and only use the link to expand the details.